# Splitting Coaxial S/PDIF

Tags: spdif

I'm looking to output a single S/PDIF output from a [BC127](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Wireless/Bluetooth/DataSheet-BC127.10.pdf) to a coaxial output as well as a [WM8804](https://d3uzseaevmutz1.cloudfront.net/pubs/proDatasheet/WM8804_v4.5.pdf) S/PDIF transceiver at the same time. So far, it doesn't appear that this works, but there could be something else at play.

Is there anything inherently wrong about outputting a single S/PDIF signal to multiple outputs?

If so, is there an IC I can use to multiplex the signal effectively?

The WM8804 appears to work fine, but the vehicle DSP attached isn't outputting any audio. I have also tried using the WM8804's S/PDIF transmitter to no avail. Without the WM8804 in play, everything appears to work fine.

Comment: You'll have to give us a lot more detail about your setup. For example, what do the signal voltages look like on the scope with one load vs. both loads connected?

Comment: Just to clarify; What kind of SPDIF it is from BC127 module, is it a 3.3V TTL logic level signal or a coaxial level signal? What kind of termination you have at WM8804 input, 75 ohm and DC blocking cap?

Comment: If both S/PDIF receivers are 75 ohm terminated, and located close to each other, you may get away with removing the termination on one of them.

Comment: @DaveTweed - Unfortunately, I don't have access to the second receiver nor a scope. I sent off a prototype to someone to have them test. I'm in the process of getting my hands on the right equipment.

Comment: @Justme - It's a standard coaxial S/PDIF output. I do have a 75ohm resistor and a DC blocking cap on the WM8804 input.

Comment: @BrianDrummond - I tried this and the WM8804 stopped working. Appreciate the suggestion, though!

Comment: I have hard time believing that the BC127 module has a SPDIF output that can directly be used for a coaxial interface. It looks like it could have a logic level output. Do you know or can measure which type of output it has?

Comment: @Justme - I have successfully output audio via coaxial from the BC127 without the WM8804 in the circuit. I don't have a scope, but I imagine a DMM can be used to measure if the output is AC or DC, right? Further, If I place the WM8804 input in TTL mode, it stops working.

Comment: @t3ddftw SPDIF can't be measured with a DMM. Well maybe for the DC component. I still don't understand the details, is the BC127 in a separate device that has coaxial output which you are using, or are you just having the BC127 module on your device and taking the output directy from there? If there is a coaxial connector, is there a coax driver/buffer driving it? At least measure SPDIF pin DC voltage on BC127 - if it is half supply voltage then it is not coax level output.

Comment: @Justme - The BC127 is directly on my PCB, and a trace is run to an SMB connector which the coax connects to. There is no coax driver/buffer in circuit at all. Where can I find more info on driving S/PDIF coaxial? I will measure the BC127 output and get back to you :)

Comment: @Justme - Never mind on the coax driver circuit -- I found some info here: http://www.hardwarebook.info/S/PDIF_output

Comment: @Justme - The S/PDIF output of the BC127 measures at 1.3v DC. I suppose this means I need to put a buffer on the coax output to bring it up to coax level, right?

Comment: @t3ddftw It proves the BC127 has logic level output and most likely too weak to drive enough current into a coaxial interface. Good thing is the WM8804 can receive logic level signals fine, so you just need to build a coax driver. That site has hobbyist circuits that may or may not be within the specifications. While a great learning source, nothing beats the real IEC 60958-3 standard. I hope you have not fried anything by connecting a logic level signal with DC average voltage directly to a SPDIF input of another device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BC127 module outputs a 3.3V logic level SPDIF signal that can be connected to multiple logic level devices, but a driver circuit is needed to properly drive a 75 ohm 0.5Vpp coaxial output interface. Connecting the logic level output directly to coaxial connector won't work and it can't drive a standard 75 ohm coaxial input.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Justme! Just out of curiosity, why does the TTL SPDIF signal measure at 1.3VDC rather than 3.3v (supply voltage)?

Comment: The data bits are encoded so that statisically the wire spends 50% of time high and 50% low so a slow measuring device sees half supply DC component.